# Submitting application on Spark Cluster using spark submit

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am new to Spark.
I want to run a Spark Structured Streaming application on cluster.
Master and workers has same configuration.

I have few queries for submitting app on cluster using spark-submit:
You may find them comical or strange.

1. How can I give path for 3rd party jars like lib/*? ( Application has 30+ jars)
2. Will Spark automatically distribute application and required jars to workers?
3. Does it require to host application on all the workers?
4. How can i know status of my application as I am working on console.

I am using following script for Spark-submit.

```
   spark-submit 
  --class <class-name> 
  --master spark://master:7077 
  --deploy-mode cluster 
  --supervise 
  --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath <jar1, jar2..jarn> 
  --executor-memory 4G 
  --total-executor-cores 8 
 <running-jar-file>
```

But code is not running as per expectation.
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

To pass multiple jar file to Spark-submit you can set the following attributes in file `SPARK_HOME_PATH/conf/spark-defaults.conf` (create if not exists):

**Don't forget to use * at the end of the paths**

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /fullpath/to/jar/folder/*
spark.executor.extraClassPath /fullpathto/jar/folder/*
```

Spark will set the attributes in the file `spark-defaults.conf` when you use the spark-submit command.
Copy your jar file on that directory and when you submit your Spark App on the cluster, the jar files in the specified paths will be loaded, too.

> **spark.driver.extraClassPath**: Extra classpath entries to prepend
>   to the classpath of the driver.  Note: In client mode, this config
>   must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application,
>   because the driver JVM has already started at that point. Instead,
>   please set this through the --driver-class-path command line option or
>   in your default properties file.

Answer (score 0):

`--jars` will transfer your jar files to worker nodes, and become available in both driver and executors' classpaths.

Please refer below link to see more details.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management

Comment: Thanks for reply... If i have hundreds of jars then what i have to do? Copying all required jars to Spark Jars directory is only solution...

Comment: Directory expansion does not work with `--jars`, so you can't point a directory which has jars on it. You may need to add all jars separated by ','.

Comment: Ok...

But copying to Spark jars will be effective or not?

Comment: When you copy your jars into Spark jars, all other applications will be affected and it may break due to dependency issue. `--jars` option would only affect on application which is submitted with such option.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a fat jar containing all dependencies. Below link helps you understand that.

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/43886/creating-fat-jars-for-spark-kafka-streaming-using.html

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please include the key parts from your link in your post. Answers that are just a link tend to be regarded as spam.